# Analytics API: I can't use two different API credentials on my PC

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I've 2 different API keys enabled on 2 different accounts. One professional and the second private and I don't want to link the 2.

My problem is that I've been working with the professional API credentials for almost 3 months and everything works fine. Now, I've created a new account with a new Analytics account and my problem is that I can't use the new API directly with my new Analytics account.

I can't make my script to authorize the new user and I receive an error that says that the user does not have sufficient permissions for this profile.

I managed to make it work by adding my private account as a user in my professional Analytics account. It seems like I can't make another account authorization even if I'm using a different API created on another account. It's like the connects to the first account authorized on my PC.

Is there any way to reset the authorization on my PC each time I want to use one of the API?

Thank you,

EDIT: I'm running a Python script that uses the Analytics API and the only time I have a prompt to authenticate it's the first time I use the application on a new PC. After that, the script runs without any prompt, The credentials are those of the API (client ID and Client secret) and I'm not using them directly but I'm using the client_serets.json file generated on the Google dev console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured it out. You'll have to navigate to this url https://myaccount.google.com/permissions?pli=1 and remove the service you want to remove.